# JSR-303 and Spring MVC Binding Result

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I'm trying to figure out how to get localized error messages when a validation error occurs.

My domain object looks like this:

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
public class Lead {

   @Email(message = "{email_error_message}")
   String emailAddress;

}
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String create(@Valid Lead lead, BindingResult result) {
    log.debug("In POST!");

    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
      FieldError fieldError = result.getFieldError("emailAddress");
      return fieldError.getDefaultMessage();
    }
    else
    {
        log.debug("Email = " + lead.getEmailAddress());
        try
        {
            lead.persist();
            lead.flush();
        }
        catch(DataAccessException ex)
        {
            log.debug("Oh OH...");
            return "Sorry we are experiencing technical difficulties, please try again later";
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

I also created ValidationMessages.properties.

```
email_error_message=Sorry your email is invalid
```

In my webmvc-config.xml :

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource"
      p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>
```

The error I get from  fieldError.getDefaultMessage() is {email_error_message}.  So the question is what am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get `message` attribute work with Spring message sources, too.

However, you can always use default message code (see [`DefaultMessageCodesResolver`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html)):

```
Email.lead.emailAddress=Sorry your email is invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

In your webmvc-config.xml, you're loading properties from application.properties.

If your ValidationMessages.properties is in the same dir, try loading it like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource"
  p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application,WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/ValidationMessages" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>
```

The other thing is if you have a webapp which users are picking locale, you don't want the message from the local runtime.  You want to get the user's session locale and use that to do the localization.

Comment: Thanks for your post! Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)