# Spring MVC JSR 303 Validation with Json response validation errors from ValidationMessages.properties

Tags: ajax, json, spring, validation, bean-validation

Hi I was looking for everywhere but can't find solution.
I am making an ajax call in Jquery function and submiting data from spring inputs form:input
to Controller. Controller is validating date by JSR 303 Hibernate Validation and return errors by JSON to the same Jquery function (receiving data by Json) and displaying errors in jsp. 
Everything work fine but displayed error messages are only dafault or from message parameter from validation annotations. I want to take error messages from ValidationMessages.properties file and i have that file with ready messages but displaying messages are dafault instead of from ValidationMessages.properties.  I am not using form:error tag because i want to display errors received by Json. Problem is that bad messages are displayed not from file but dafault.

I will add that while doing normal JSR 303 Validation (without Ajax and Json) displaying error messages by form:error tag  everything works fine and messages come from ValidationMessages.properties file.

My .jsp page

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Add Users using ajax</title>
         <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/jquery.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">
           var contexPath = "<%=request.getContextPath() %>";
         </script>
         <script src="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/js/user.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/style/app.css">
     </head>

       <body>
          <h1>Add Users using Ajax ........</h1>
           <form:form method="post"  modelAttribute="user">
           <table>
                <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="error" class="error"></div></td></tr> 
                   <tr><td>Name:</td> <td><form:input path="name" /></td> 
                <tr><td>Education</td> <td><form:input path="education" /></td> 

                <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add Users" onclick="doAjaxPost()"><br/></td></tr>

                <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="info" class="success"></div></td></tr>
          </table>

  </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

My doAjaxPost function in user.js

```
      function doAjaxPost() {  
  // get the form values  
  var name = $('#name').val();
  var education = $('#education').val();

  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: contexPath + "/AddUser.htm",  
    data: "name=" + name + "&education=" + education,  
    success: function(response){
      // we have the response 
      if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
          userInfo = "<ol>";
          for(i =0 ; i < response.result.length ; i++){
              userInfo += "<br><li><b>Name</b> : " + response.result[i].name + 
              ";<b> Education</b> : " + response.result[i].education;
          }
          userInfo += "</ol>";
          $('#info').html("User has been added to the list successfully. " + userInfo);
          $('#name').val('');
          $('#education').val('');
          $('#error').hide('slow');
          $('#info').show('slow');
      }else{

          errorInfo = "";
          for(i =0 ; i < response.result.length ; i++){

              errorInfo += "<br>" + (i + 1) +". " + response.result[i].defaultMessage;

          }
          $('#error').html("Please correct following errors: " + errorInfo);

          $('#info').hide('slow');
          $('#error').show('slow');

      }       
    },  
    error: function(e){  
      alert('Error: ' + e);  
    }  
  });  
}
```

Here is a Controller

```
  package com.raistudies.controllers;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;
  import java.util.Map;

   import javax.validation.Valid;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

   import com.raistudies.domain.JsonResponse;
   import com.raistudies.domain.User;

  @Controller
  public class UserController {
private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>(); 

@RequestMapping(value="/AddUser.htm",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(Map model){
    User user = new User();
    model.put("user", user);
    return "AddUser";
}


@RequestMapping(value="/AddUser.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody JsonResponse addUser(@ModelAttribute(value="user") @Valid User user, BindingResult result ){
    JsonResponse res = new JsonResponse();

    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        userList.add(user);
        res.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        res.setResult(userList);

    }else{
        res.setStatus("FAIL");
        res.setResult(result.getAllErrors());

    }

    return res;
}

  }
```

User Class

```
 package com.raistudies.domain;

 import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

 import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

 public class User {

@NotEmpty
private String name = null;

@NotEmpty
@Size(min=6, max=20)
private String education = null;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEducation() {
    return education;
}
public void setEducation(String education) {
    this.education = education;
}

  }
```

Here is ValidationMessage.properties file

```
  NotEmpty.user.name=Name of user cant be empty
  NotEmpty.user.education = User education cant be empty
  Size.education=education must hava between 6 and 20 digits
```

Here is app-config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Application Message Bundle -->
   <bean id="messageSource"    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/ValidationMessages" />
</bean>


<!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.raistudies" />

<!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
<mvc:annotation-driven/>



<!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>



   </beans>
```

Here is a Screenshot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xsmupm1cgtv4x7/image.png?v=0mcns

As You see there are displaying default error messages not from ValidationMessages.properties file. How to solve that?

Comment: I think that is the same problem as described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073488/jsr-303-and-spring-mvc-binding-result. I think the problem is that Spring puts several layers on top of pure Bean Validation validation and validation behaves differently depending on what you do in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this is a very old question, but I've been trying to solve this for some time. Since I just found a *work around* this, I thought to share it to help others possibly stuck on the same thing.

Beware that I'm doing this with **java config**, therefore I use annotations.

First, on the controller, add an autowired link to the environment. This is to be able to read the property file:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;
```

The OP already has the messageSource defined through XML, but in java config it would be on the config class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. In my case, it worked with:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
   ResourceBundleMessageSource msg= new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
   msg.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
   msg.setBasename("PATH_TO_YOUR_MESSAGE_FILE");
   msg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
   return msg;
}
```

Make sure to replace that part with the path to your file. In any case, now to solve the issue. Back on the controller, replace this line:

```
res.setResult(result.getAllErrors());
```

For this one, and call a new function:

```
createErrorMessages(result.getFieldErrors());
```

Now, this is the new method that converts the messages:

```
private LinkedList<CustomErrorMsg> createErrorMessages(List<FieldError> originalErrors) {
    // Create a new list of error message to be returned
    LinkedList<CustomErrorMsg> newErrors = new LinkedList<>();

    // Iterate through the original errors
    for(FieldError fe: originalErrors) {
        // If the codes are null, then put the default message,
        // if not, then get the first code from the property file.
        String msg = (fe.getCodes() == null) ? fe.getDefaultMessage()
                : environment.getProperty(fe.getCodes()[0]);

        // Create the new error and add it to the list
        newErrors.add(new CustomErrorMsg(fe.getField(), msg));
    }

    // Return the message
    return newErrors;
}
```

The if part makes it work for the cases where there are no codes, and also for when you perform a business logic validation check on the controller, and manually add a new field error.

This work around does not work with parameters on the customs messages. On another note, if you happen to have other pages that use hibernate validation but do not need the AJAX callback, you will not need to use this strategy. Those simply work as default.

I'm very aware this is not *elegant* at all, and it may add a little more code than desired, but as I said before, it is a "work around".

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="messageInterpolator" ref="messageSource"/>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator"/>
```

The idea is to explicitly tell the Validator which message source to use. I have not tried this myself, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: This is a good idea, but sadly, it won't work because the messageInterpolator property isn't writable.